# Cannot find a value from the local configuration manager?

Tags: 8, commerce

In D8 in the configuration manager I have a value:

CURRENT VALUE FOR COMMERCE_PAYMENT.COMMERCE_PAYMENT_GATEWAY.COINPAYMENTS

with YAML file

```
uuid: xxxx
langcode: en
status: true
dependencies:
  module:
    - commerce_coinpayments
id: coinpayments
label: Coinpayments
weight: null
plugin: coinpayments_redirect
configuration:
  business: ''
  allow_supported_currencies: '1'
  ipn_logging: 'yes'
  merchant: ''
  ipn_secret: xxxxxx
  display_label: 'Pay with Bitcoin, Litecoin, and other of more then 50 cryptocurrencies.'
  mode: test
  payment_method_types:
    - credit_card
  merchant_id: 1111
  currency_code: EUR
conditions: {  }
conditionOperator: AND
```

The values are changed for privacy of course.

I tried the retrieve the value of Merchant_id with code:

```
trim($this->commerceCoinpayments->get('configuration')['merchant_id']));
```

But still this is empty. How is this possible?

Comment: What's `$this->commerceCoinpayments`?

Comment: Yeah, without knowing that, we can't help.